# Search data in listbox in form 1 on another listbox in form2

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a problem with this code, I want to search on listbox4 on form2 in listbox 5 on form1.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d40U.jpg]

I used this code as shown as below:

```
int index= eski.listbox5.FindString(listbox4.ToString());
if(index= !=-1)
    eski[enter image description here][1].listbox5.SetSelected(index ,true);
else
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing Found")
```

Programme finds the true index value but set selected command doesn't work..

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`listbox4.ToString()` is just going to return the control as a string. Call `listBox4.GetItemText(listBox4.SelectedItem)` instead. Also, line 2 should be `if (index != -1)`

Comment: i tried this but doesn't work :(

it can't find the value in listbox 5 in form1 index comes -1 always ..

Comment: @Onurİn Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: i use WinForms also.

Comment: When i search value between listboxes in same form it works!
But searching value in form2 in form 1 it doesn't..